# Override New Section Style to Look Default in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, color, tocloft

I need to change the sections, subsections, etc., styles. And I did. The problem is I need the table of contents to keep the default style.

The text colour in my new style is white, so the TOC appears to have no section titles. And the `tocloft` `\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\color{black}}` is not overriding that change for the TOC.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\color{black}}

\newcommand*{\newSection}[1]{
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        center title,
        left=0pt,
        right=0pt,
        top=0pt,
        bottom=0pt,
        colback=blue!75,
        colframe=white,
        width=\dimexpr\textwidth\relax,
        enlarge left by=0mm,
        boxsep=5pt,
        arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt]
        \section{\textcolor{white}{#1}}
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\let\oldthesection\thesection
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\textcolor{white}{\oldthesection}}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \newSection{Section}
  \newSection{Another Section}
  \newSection{And One More}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `titlesec` makes it much easier to change the formatting of the section titles without affecting the TOC or other locations:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newtcolorbox{sectionbox}{
    center title,
    left=0pt,
    right=0pt,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    colback=blue!75,
    colframe=white,
    width=\dimexpr\textwidth\relax,
    enlarge left by=0mm,
    boxsep=5pt,
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt
}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
    {\begin{sectionbox}\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{white}}
    {\thesection}
    {1em}
    {}
    [\end{sectionbox}]

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Section}
\section{Another Section}
\section{And One More}
\end{document}
```

[image: The resulting document]

Answer (score 1):

Without using `tocloft` or `titlesec`, just providing the correct option handling and redefining `\@seccntformat` which is to be preferred concerning the change of the numbering format of section titles.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\let\@old@seccntformat\@seccntformat
\NewDocumentCommand{\newSection}{O{#2}mO{}}{
  \begin{tcolorbox}[
   enhanced,
    frame hidden,
    center title,
    left=0pt,
    right=0pt,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    colback=blue!75,
    colframe=white,
    boxsep=5pt,
    sharp corners,
    #3
    ]
    \begingroup
    \renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
      \ifnum0=\pdfstrcmp{##1}{section}%
      \textcolor{white}{\@old@seccntformat{##1}}%
      \else
      \@old@seccntformat{##1}%
      \fi
    }
    \section[\color{black}#1]{\textcolor{white}{#2}}%
    \endgroup
  \end{tcolorbox}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \newSection{Section}
  \newSection{Another Section}
  \newSection{And One More}
  \newSection{Don't screw up the layout}
\end{document}
```

[image]